# Postgresql: Update parent column based on child column in adjacency model

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table which models a hierarchical data using adjacency model.

`|----------|--------|--------|--------|
 | ParentID |     ID |  Flag  |   Name |
 |----------|--------|--------|--------|
 |    0     |      1 |        |    x   |
 |----------|--------|--------|--------|
 |    1     |      2 |        |    y   |
 |----------|--------|--------|--------|
 |    2     |      3 |        |    z   |
 |----------|--------|--------|--------|`

I have a SELECT query which sets the Flag if name does not matches certain patterns.

```
SELECT r.id, r.pid, r.name, r.name NOT LIKE ALL(ARRAY[patterns to
match]) AS r.flag FROM TABLE1 AS r
```

Now i want to flag the parents also if the child was flagged. How can i acheive that?

Comment: What is the data type for the Flag column? I assume you are looking to build an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @GregViers Datatype of flag is boolean. This select statement is done on temp table returned by another query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `left self join` will allow you to find the parent fields. `BOOL_OR` can be used to aggregate the children if there are more than one.

```
SELECT r.id, r.pid, r.name,
CASE WHEN r.name NOT LIKE ALL(ARRAY[patterns to match]) THEN True ELSE 
BOOL_OR(child.name NOT LIKE ALL(ARRAY[patterns to match])) END AS r.flag
FROM TABLE1 AS r
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 as child on child.pid=r.id
GROUP BY r.id, r.pid, r.name, r.name NOT LIKE ALL(ARRAY[patterns to match])
```

Comment: Thanks. with little tweak in your query i got what i wanted